# SleepConditionVariableCS will hang

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization, condition-variable

I modified the "[Using Condition Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx)" example in MSDN. I created several threads, which have their own producer/consumer separately.
But the program will often hang when attached to debugger. It always hangs at `SleepConditionVariableCS`. When I break all and continue in debugger, the program will continue to run. I found that WakeAllConditionVariable didn't wake up some thread calls SleepConditionVariableCS, for the Ptr in PExecutingTask->BufferNotFull or PExecutingTask->BufferNotEmpty was already 0x00000000(I thought that means the condition variable is wakened).
When not attached to debugger, the program will not hang.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? How to solve it?

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

DWORD WINAPI ProducerThreadProc (PVOID p);
DWORD WINAPI ConsumerThreadProc (PVOID p);
class ExecutingTask
{
public:
    void Initialize()
    {
        InitializeConditionVariable (&BufferNotEmpty);
        InitializeConditionVariable (&BufferNotFull);

        InitializeCriticalSection (&BufferLock);

        QueueSize = 0;
        StopRequested = FALSE;

        hProducer = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ProducerThreadProc, (PVOID)this, 0, NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            PhConsumers[i] = CreateThread (NULL, 0, ConsumerThreadProc, (PVOID)this, 0, NULL);
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        EnterCriticalSection (&BufferLock);
        StopRequested = TRUE;
        LeaveCriticalSection (&BufferLock);

        WakeAllConditionVariable (&BufferNotFull);
        WakeAllConditionVariable (&BufferNotEmpty);

        WaitForSingleObject(hProducer, INFINITE);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(20, (HANDLE *)&PhConsumers, true, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hProducer);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            CloseHandle(PhConsumers[i]);
        }
    }

public:
    ULONG QueueSize;

    CONDITION_VARIABLE BufferNotEmpty;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE BufferNotFull;
    CRITICAL_SECTION   BufferLock;

    BOOL StopRequested;

    HANDLE PhConsumers[20];
    HANDLE hProducer;
};

DWORD WINAPI ProducerThreadProc (PVOID p)
{
    ExecutingTask* PExecutingTask = (ExecutingTask*)p;

    while (true)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);

        while (PExecutingTask->QueueSize >= BUFFER_SIZE && PExecutingTask->StopRequested == FALSE)
        {
            // Buffer is full - sleep so consumers can get items.
            SleepConditionVariableCS (&PExecutingTask->BufferNotFull, &PExecutingTask->BufferLock, INFINITE);
        }

        if (PExecutingTask->StopRequested == TRUE)
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);
            break;
        }

        // Produce an item.
        PExecutingTask->QueueSize++;
        LeaveCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);
        WakeConditionVariable (&PExecutingTask->BufferNotEmpty);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ConsumerThreadProc (PVOID p)
{
    ExecutingTask* PExecutingTask = (ExecutingTask*)p;

    while (true)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);

        while (PExecutingTask->QueueSize == 0 && PExecutingTask->StopRequested == FALSE)
        {
            // Buffer is empty - sleep so producers can create items.
            SleepConditionVariableCS (&PExecutingTask->BufferNotEmpty, &PExecutingTask->BufferLock, INFINITE);
        }

        if (PExecutingTask->StopRequested == TRUE)
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);
            break;
        }

        // Consume an item.
        PExecutingTask->QueueSize--;
        LeaveCriticalSection (&PExecutingTask->BufferLock);
        WakeConditionVariable (&PExecutingTask->BufferNotFull);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc (PVOID p)
{
    ExecutingTask task;
    task.Initialize();
    Sleep(1000);
    task.Stop();

    printf ("%u exit\n", &task);

    return 0;
};

int main ( void )
{
    HANDLE hTaskThreads[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        hTaskThreads[i] = CreateThread (NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(50, hTaskThreads, true, INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hTaskThreads[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which call to `SleepConditionVariableCS` is it hanging in?

Comment: Does the unmodified program hang? If not, then the changes you made must have broken something. I would look there for the cause.

Comment: You should add the debug output that exists in the original sample (the output lines that show when each thread adds or removes an item, and when it exits). Also, pare down your program so that it only creates *one* thread, and change the `ExecutingTask` so that it creates one producer and one or two consumers. That will make your debugging much easier. Once that works, you can increase your thread count. But 50 tasks each creating one producer and 20 consumers is a bit extreme.

Comment: I would suggest moving the `WakeConditionVariable()` calls before the `LeaveCriticalSection()` calls instead of after, otherwise you have a race condition on signaling the condition variables. Also, you do not need to lock the critical section when calling `StopRequested = TRUE`.

Comment: There are two SleepConditionVariableCS calls in the program, and both of them will hang.